# Custom control becomes generic "UserControl" and not its actual type in Designer class

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, ascx

I have a custom control in ASP.NET (VB.NET in code behind), defined with an ASCX:

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="MyControl.ascx.vb" Inherits="Mynamespace.Controls.MyControl" %>

<!-- some html and other custom controls-->
```

And in code behind:

```
Namespace Controls

    Public Class MyControl
        Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

This is set in a library. A different project uses that control in a page:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="mypage.aspx.vb" 
    Inherits="myproject.mypage" culture="auto" meta:resourcekey="Page" uiculture="auto" 
    Transaction="RequiresNew" MasterPageFile="Mynamespace.Master" 
    Theme="ThemeBase2" StylesheetTheme="ThemeBase2" %>

<%@ Register tagprefix="Controls" tagname="MyControl" src="../Controls/MyControl.ascx" %>

<%-- some asp.net --%>

<Controls:MyControl ID="mycontrol1" runat="server" 
                    MyCustomProperty="value" />
```

However, when I build, I get an error saying

> 'MyCustomProperty' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.UserControl'.

And in the designer.vb page I see:

```
Protected WithEvents mycontrol1 As Global.System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

How do I ensure it becomes:

```
Protected WithEvents mycontrol1 As Global.Mynamespace.Controls.MyControl
```

?

Comment: I'm not sure referencing *user controls* (as opposed to regular server controls) in another project is a supported scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ascx file is not accessible because it is in a library

You need to save the ascx file as an embedded resource of your library and load it as extern resource in your web application.

You can consult this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15494/Load-WebForms-and-UserControls-from-Embedded-Resou) for more informations.

If you want share yours controls, i advise to create UserControl instead of CustomControl. Unfortunately, there is more work because the designer is not usable

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that `MyControl` is defined inside `Global.Mynamespace.Controls.MyControl`. It inherits this namespace, but it seems that this is supposed to be the namespace in which it is defined. Also, make sure that MyCustomProperty is defined, of course.

Comment: I tried specifying `Global.Mynamespace.Controls.MyControl` explicitely in the code behind of the control, no dice.

Comment: @MPelletier I have edited my answer. I hope this helps.

Comment: I can't do that. That's my page's code behind. I need that. And besides, I have other custom controls.